# How do I connect two rows inserted with unknown id

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have this system with some accounting features. Let's say there are two accounts and I want to transfer money between these two accounts. acc1(id 1) acc2(id 2). So I want to transfer money from 1 to 2. I have this transactions table. For this transfer, I insert two rows to transactions table. First transaction takes the money from acc1 and the second transaction puts that money to acc2. How do I connect these two transactions? I need another id which will be the same for these two transactions. TransactionID field is Auto Increment, I can't know what will be the id. I can create a sequence of random numbers in mod 10000 but everytime I have to check if there is a transaction with the generated id. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you going to do with this new ID?

Comment: let's say transfer id column for both transaction 1 and 2 is 10 then I will be able to say that transaction 1 is connected with 2. Later if I want to edit one of these transactions I have to change the corresponding transaction so that things stay in tact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a new table `Transfers`. It would be like:

```
CREATE TABLE Transfers (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    from_transaction_id INT,
    to_transaction_id INT,
    UNIQUE INDEX from_to (from_transaction_id, to_transaction_id),
    FOREIGN KEY from_transaction_id REFERENCES Transactions (id),
    FOREIGN KEY to_transaction_id REFERENCES Transactions (id)
);
```

After you add the withdrawal and deposit transactions to the `Transactions` table, you can add a row to `Transfers` with the IDs of those two transactions.